# add error and send request back to request page servlet filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I am writing a servlet filter. I want to add error  and send the response back to page from which the request has come.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        final HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
       final HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
       //add error and redirect the request to previous page
       chain.doFilter(request, response);

}
```

I know that we can redirect the response as

```
servletResponse.sendRedirect("/WebContent/Error.jsp");
```

Please let me know how can add error message and send the request back.

I want to add some custom error message.`"Validation failed. Please try again".`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

servletResponse.[sendError](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)() ??